# Google geocoder API: Lookup partial postal code (Germany)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to build an autocomplete where people can start typing a postal code, and get meaningful suggestions before the postal code is complete.

#### Existing example

An existing example can be found here: https://weisse-liste.de/de/arzt/arztsuche/

Typing "120" in "Ort oder Postleitzahl" gets a list of suggestions where the postal code starts with "120". I am not affiliated with this site, and don't know if they are even using the Google geocoding API. (The request goes to their own server, then they do something with it.)

#### Attempt with Google geocoding API

The closest I can get with Google API is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=120&sensor=false&components=country:DE

But the only result this gives me is the one with "formatted_address" : "Germany", so the entire country.

#### EDIT: client-side js vs server-side php / handcrafted request url

The existing answer proposes client-side javascript. Which is totally valid given the question.

It would still be interesting to see an answer giving a hand-crafted url similar to the one above, which can be used in a server-side request. If this is not possible, no problem. An advantage could be privacy of the visitor, by avoiding a client-side request to Google. I am not even saying this is a good idea, but it could still be useful  information.

Comment: Why is this -1 ? I am aware that the example makes requests to their own server, and the question makes this clear. They could still be doing server-side requests to Google, same as Drupal's [Geocoder autocomplete](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/geocoder_autocomplete/tree/geocoder_autocomplete.module) module. But even if not, it still illustrates what I am looking for behavior-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side variant of the request is the following:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=120&types=(regions)&components=country%3ADE&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You can read about Places API Autocomplete web service at

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: With `types=(regions)`, a number like "520" as search string will be interpreted as the first letters of a zipcode. Which is good. On the other hand, street names lead to "ZERO_RESULTS". With "types=geocode", street names are accepted, but a search string like "520" will be interpreted as a house number. Maybe I can build some logic on top of this, to decide whether to use types=geocode or types=(regions). This problem seems to be the same for server-side and client-side API requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing example does not use Google Geocoder, it has its own query:
https://weisse-liste.de/api/zip/suggest?term=120

You can also do it e.g. with PHP and MySQL, but then you should have the complete list of postal codes. And I think that would be another topic.

I can show you an Place Autocomplete javascript example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5377x9y8/

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var options = {
  types: ['(regions)'],
  componentRestrictions: {'country': 'de'}
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var address = '';
  if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
  }
  document.getElementById('addr').innerHTML = '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address;
});
```

Unfortunately it does not give the whole list of postal codes, because the result is restricted to 5 items.
But I hope this can help you.

Comment: It looks good! I don't care the 5 items limitation. But in my current implementation, the request happens on server side with PHP.. My network tab says e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1s5&4sen-US&7scountry%3Ade&9s(regions)&15e3&callback=_xdc_._tmud9t&token=2885 I wonder if there is a way to craft these urls by hand?

Comment: I marked the other answer as "accepted". But this does not mean that this answer is wrong or inferior. I just had to pick one, and the other was closer to my personal intent. Btw my comment there about types=(regions) vs types=geocode applies equally to this answer.